ListView inside ListView is building all item at once
On my screen I need to display a ListView inside an other ListView. The screen can be summarized like this:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Isolate FutureBuilder Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Header"),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text("Filters"),
            SizedBox(height: 32),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 3,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("List $index"),
                      SizedBox(height: 32),
                      ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: 50,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            print("building $index");
                            return Text("$index");
                          })
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

If you try it, you will se that all the 200 items of the inner ListView.builder are built immediately, causing an UI jam in my main app since I have many more and more complex items.
How can I prevent this and keep the ListView behavior that builds only the visible items? I read that shrinkWrap: true can be the cause, but if I set it to false I have an error Vertical viewport was given unbounded height. and I am not able to fix it

why are you usisng a listview inside  a listview?

Can you add your expected output result image? and I think you dont need Listview inside Listview

@IldebertoVasconcelos because on my app, the outer ListView doesn't have just a Text and the other ListView, but more, and they have to scroll

You can try this code
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Isolate FutureBuilder Example'),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Isolate FutureBuilder Example'),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Header"),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                Text("Filters"),
                SizedBox(height: 32),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ...Iterable.generate(3, (index) {
            return [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("List $index"),
                    const SizedBox(height: 32),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SliverList.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print("building $index");
                  return Text("$index");
                },
                itemCount: 50,
              )
            ];
          }).toList().expand((element) => element).toList()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

here the nested list view is broken into flat listview using CustomScrollView and Slivers.

thanks, this actually helped me, i didn't consider to use CustomScrollView with slivers. Since I also need to have a toggle function to show/hide the inner list, i ended up using this https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_expandable

try to replace your code with this
i think you don't need a listview inside a listview
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Isolate FutureBuilder Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Header"),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text("Filters"),
            SizedBox(height: 32),
            Text("List 1"),
            SizedBox(height: 32),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5, // Adjust height as needed
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: 200,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        print("building $index");
                        return Text("$index");
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


maybe I have summarized to much... I need the outer ListView because its children come from a list, so I don't have just a Text and the other list, but more instances, so like (List 1, [...]),  (List 2, [...]), (List 3, [...]), and i want to display all of them scrolling

I have updated the code with a thing more similar to my case

understood
so ,i think the way to do this,is by setting a height for your inner listview
i've updated the code also
